# How to correct strange character to be normal when importing '.csv' file in My SQL query browser?

Tags: mysql, csv, utf-8

I am facing big problem to correct strange chinese character to be normal when importing '.csv' file in My SQL query browser. When I import the CSV data, it will show me like below the picture:

The database has already change to UTF-8 format, but it show me the strange chinese character:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJrWa.png)

My SQL query like the below:

```
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
    'c:/2019/countries20.csv'
    INTO TABLE countries
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (id,name,country_code,language);
```

My CSV file info like the below picture, I have change CSV file encode to UTF-8:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMWEI.png)

Anyone can help me find which part I get wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share the sample data as formatted text here instead of Images. Btw Images are not a good practices here unless it's an extra info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include in the `LOAD DATA`: `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

Declare the target column to be `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.